# Power Query - How to find rows with the same status but different dates

Tags: powerquery

I have this data and there are status that are repeating but with older dates and i want to remove the older dates of the same status.

Create two separate columns where the older dates of the same status will become blank

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7q2K.png)]

Comment: Please post data as text not images. We don't want to retype things to help you

Comment: Thank you got it. will do moving forward

Answer (score 0):

Try this in powerquery. I grouped on [vacancy, company, recruiter, status] but you can change that

```
    let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
 #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Status Start Date", type date}}),
 #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
 #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Index", {"Vacancy Reference", "Company", "Main Recruiter", "Status"}, {
     {"data", each 
         let a=List.Max(_[Status Start Date]),
         b=Table.AddColumn(_,"Status2", each [Status]),
         c=Table.AddColumn(b,"Status Start Date2", each if [Status Start Date]<a then null else [Status Start Date])
         in c
     , type table }}),
     #"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Status Start Date", "Index", "Status2", "Status Start Date2"}, {"Status Start Date", "Index", "Status2", "Status Start Date2"}),
 #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded data",{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
 #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index"}),
 #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns" ,{{"Status Start Date2", type date}, {"Status Start Date", type date}})
 in #"Changed Type2"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Is there another way where when you pivot in power query it will take only the earlier dates?

I tried this formula but did not work - 
= Table.Pivot(PreviousStepName,List.Distinct(PrevousStepName[Status]),"Status","Status Start Date",List.Min)

Comment: Are you just looking for the earliest date and then remove the other rows ? That was not your original question

Comment: Yes, im trying to test but my main goal is to pivot the Statuses as column and the dates will serve as its value however there are the same status with different dates and i want if possible to capture only the earlier dates.

Comment: Or = Table.Group(#"PriorStepNameHere", {"Status"}, {{"MinDate", each List.Max([Status Start Date]), type nullable date}})    or Group on desired columns, date and status. In group options choose max on date field. Expand the results